# How to get values from dynamic table using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.6

I have following Code in my view.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<tr class="cat-row">
<td class="cat-id">{{$category->id}}</td>
<td>{{$category->name}}</td>
<td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Get ID</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

If I want to get a simple alert with the id of the current row by clicking the Get ID button, what should I do in jquery?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar
I tried follwoing but it's not working...

 $('.cat-id').each(function () {
            $('.btn-danger').click(function () {
                alert($('.cat-id').text());
            });
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my contribution.

Something very similar to what [Kapsonfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5214689/kapsonfire) wrote.

---

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', (e) => {
  let target = e.target;
  let topmostParent = target.parentElement.parentElement;
  let id = $(topmostParent).find('.cat-id').text();
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="cat-row">
    <td class="cat-id">123</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Get ID</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="cat-row">
    <td class="cat-id">124</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Get ID</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="cat-row">
    <td class="cat-id">125</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Get ID</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="cat-row">
    <td class="cat-id">126</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Get ID</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

give the get id button a proper selector like class '.getid'

```
$(document).on('click', '.getid', function() {
 let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cat-id').text();
 console.log(id);
});
```

you have to bind the listener to document to apply on dynamically inserted dom

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for that

```js
$(".getId").on('click',function() {
 let id = $(this).attr('id');
 console.log(id);
});
```

```html
/*PHP File*/

@foreach($categories as $category)
<tr class="cat-row">
<td class="cat-id">{{$category->id}}</td>
<td>{{$category->name}}</td>
<td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger getId" data-id="{{$category->id}}">Get ID</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```